# ¿Como Muestro Una Tabla de Muiltiplicar en java con JPanel y JFrame form?

Tags: java, método, jframe

Quiero que al presionar un botón despliegue una tabla de multiplicar pero no me lanza errores y no se si lo eso haciendo bien.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ContainerListener;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author root
 */
public class Panel extends JPanel{
    private int x;
    private JTextArea mostrarMulti;
private int tablas=11;
private int multi = 0;
private JTextField num1;
private String resultado;

public Panel(JTextArea mostrarMulti, JTextField num1) {
    this.mostrarMulti=mostrarMulti;
    this.num1=num1;
}

public void mostrar(){
    x=Integer.parseInt(num1.getText());//convierte el texto ingresado en un valor numerico
    for (int i = 1; i < tablas; i++) {
          multi=x*i;
          //etiqueta.setText(resultado);
          mostrarMulti.append(x+"*"+i"="+multi);
    }
    mostrarMulti.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Alex, tu código solo realiza la tabla del `0` , necesitas toda la tabla ? por qué reasignas el valor del texto de tu `JLabel` , no se llegará a mostrar los valores , dado que será muy rápido el proceso. Para obtener la tabla de multiplicar bastaría dos ciclos `for`

Comment: Alex, si pones un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) recibirás una respuesta. Bienvenido a SO.

Comment: utilize el formulario jframe y lo que trato de hacer es que el valor numerico pase a ser una cadena de texto la multiplicacion la realiza par no se como lograr que se muestre en el jlabel

Answer (score 1):

tienes tu campo de texto

```
private javax.swing.JTextField txtNumero;
```

tienes tu JTextArea donde se mostrara la tabla de multiplicar

```
private javax.swing.JTextArea txtMostrarMulti;
```

guardamos el numero en una variable

```
int numero = Integer.parseInt(txtNumero.getText());
```

en esta variable guardaremos la cadena resultante al hacer los calculos quedara algo asi
 2x1=2
 2x2=4

```
String salida = "";
```

tenemos el ciclo que permitira iterar de 0 hasta 11 para obtener la tabla de multiplicar de 0 hasta 11

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
        int resultado = numero * i;
        salida += numero + "x" + i + "=" + resultado + "\n";

    }
```

al final ya la cadena salida tiene el resultado por lo que hacemos lo siguiente

```
txtMostrarMulti.append(salida);
```

espero te sirva!

Comment: de hecho en la parte de salida dentro del for me sale error

Comment: Excelente aporte, me ayudó mucho, gracias!!!